# swing.timer working but has some bug

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a working app, but very fast timer gets confused.

The idea is to to load data from database to two JTables every 100s and constantly switch between them every 10 seconds. Have everything working but after a few. I am posting the simple example of the problem, please help me find the bug, this is my first time with swing.timers and i guess it is something trivial:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable pTable ;
    private JTable cTable;
    private Timer timer;
    private Timer worker;
    public int flag=0;
    public int flip=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    initialize();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void initialize(){
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            Test frame = new Test();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
        }   
    }

    public Test() {
        try{

            setTitle("Warehouse stats");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            ActionListener work = new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    flip=0;
                    // this is where i would load the tables from DB
                    pTable = new JTable(10,10);
                    cTable = new JTable(5,5);


              ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
                {   
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                       if(flip==0){
                           scrollPane.setViewportView(pTable);  
                           flip=1;
                       }else if (flip==1){
                           scrollPane.setViewportView(cTable);
                           flip=0;
                       }    

                    }
                };


                timer = new Timer(10*1000,action);
                timer.setInitialDelay(0);
                if(!timer.isRunning()){
                timer.start();
                }
                }
            };

            worker = new Timer(100*1000,work);
            worker.setInitialDelay(0);
            worker.start();

        }catch (Exception e2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are, repeatedly, creating a new `Timer` every 100 seconds, which is accumulative, that is, the second time the timer triggers, you will have two `Timer`s ticking at 10 second intervals, and then 4, then 8, 16, 32...I'd consider using a `SwingWorker` perhaps, or separate the two `Timer`s, so the second is not created in the first...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i knew that is was that...but didn't know how to make a work around..thanks...any input is more than welcomed.

Comment: @MadProgrammer if one is loading the tables and the other timer is switching between the setViewportView with those tables...how will the timer that is flipping back and forth show the tables in the moment that that the first is loading them ? solving this will solve the problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer i just took the one that switches tables from out the worker timer...hope that works

Comment: Only one Timer can be executing its ActionListener at a time, this is one of benefits of how this type of timer works, so it's impossible for the data to be loading while the tables are been flipped. Also remember, Timers are re-entrant, this means you can start and stop them multiple times